# C++ Using a space in memory when the required size is unknown

Tags: c++

I'm working on a little project in C++ where the full result of an operation will be ultimately written to a file. This operation is done on small chunks of a potentially large matrix. Since constantly writing to the disk each time a chunk is processed seems rather inefficient, I thought it would be better to store all the partial results in memory and then write a single time to the file. The problem is that the output of processing each chunk of data can have a variable size, and there is no way of knowing the needed size before processing. So I was wondering, what can I use as a buffer for storing all the partial results? I have thought of using a vector, but since I am not very familiar with C++ I figured I would ask if there is a better way.

Comment: What kind of OS do you use?

Comment: If you use e.g. [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or [`std::deque`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) you don't have to know the size before-hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ofstreams are already buffered, as are C FILE streams. Under both of those, the OS performs buffering and I/O scheduling.

Just use them naively, and don't worry about reinventing it unless profiling shows your I/O is a bottleneck.

Comment: So I can keep writing to my ofstream and when everything is ready, just write its content to a file?

Comment: @AlexTerreaux When the buffer is full, it will be automatically written to disk. You don't have to do anything special.

Comment: Please note: std::endl automatically flushes the buffer.